How to get files path dynamically in R?
I created a R script that automate some data processing tasks and I wish to share it with others coworkers without knowledge of R. The idea is to create a zip file with R and the script where the user will insert the data in a specific folder and then just run a batch script that will call Rscript in CMD and run the routine.
The problem is I don't know where they will extract the zip so the program can be in any folder. Some people could extract it in a disk C others in disk D and in any possible folder.
I already figured out a way of calling the script using a batch file because once I put the batch script in the root of the project I can get the directory using %~dp0 and from it I can find any path that I need.
The problem is how I will load libraries inside the R script if I don't know where the library folder will be? If I knew at least where it would be I could use something like this.path::here() to the directory inside R.
At first I thought about writting the path with batch and the load it in r, but I din't find a way to read it into r since I wouldn't know the exact path from where it will come.

There is quite a lot of unpack in your answer as you seem to operate on a lot of unwritten assumptions.
For instance:

What is in zip file?
Why run Rscript script.r inside another batch script? You could run Rscript script.r directly.
What libraries are you talking about? Packages are typically loaded using library(). Where the packages are stored should not be concern. Are you sourceing some other code that is being provided in the zip file?

There are multiple ways to solve your problem, but all of them are dependent on how you want the user to interface with your solution.
If your users are comfortable using a command line, it is easy. An Rscript with command-line arguments is all you need. No need for any hard-coded folder, just have it as an argument. Either code argparsing yourself, or use R pkg argparser or something similar.
Otherwise, it gets a little bit complicated. But see these answers: Compile R script into standalone .exe file?
Your "Where is my script" is easily solvable with commandArgs(FALSE), just parse the "--file=" element.
set_script_dir = function(){
    commandArgs(FALSE)
    dir = commandArgs(FALSE) |>
        grep(pattern="^--file=", value=TRUE) |>
        sub(pattern="^--file=", replacement="") |>
        dirname()
    setwd(dir)
    }

if(sys.nframe() == 0) set_script_dir()

I believe that the above code is self-explanatory.
It sets the directory to the directory of the script, but only if the script itself is being executed. I haven't tested it on anything else than the R console, since I typically run R only through the terminal.
